# I want only string value from JSON.Stringify

Tags: angularjs, json

```
alert(JSON.stringify(Attendances.data));
```

It gives this result:

```
[{"EmpNTLogin":"Gautam"}]
```

What I want:

```
"Gautam"
```

Comment: alert(JSON.stringify(Attendances.data[0].EmpNTLogin)); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to stringify it.

```
alert(Attendances.data[0].EmpNTLogin);
```

`Attendances.data` is an array of JSON objects, that each have an `EmpNTLogin` property. `Attendances.data[0]` gets the first JSON object in the array, and `.EmpNTLogin` gets the value associated with the `EmpNTLogin` property, in this case "Guatam".